# wordpress comment like dislike more like show post on top

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, customization

I have using WP Advanced Comment ( PRO ) plugin
i have added post comment like or dislike, when you post like a post comment then this Post comment show the top.
how it's possible 
[link](http://hellogoogle.co.uk/what-does-spamdexing-mean/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow this steps.

Go to **Settings -> Discussion -> Other comment settings -> Change "Comments should be displayed with 'older' to 'newer' the comments at the top of each page"**

This will show the newer comments at top.

**Sort by likes,**

Go to shortcodes/comment-form.php in plugin,

Find this line in the file ,

```
$results_arr = $this->get_comment_enable_disable( $status , $id , $post->ID , $per_page , $offset , $order_by , $pin_arr['exclude_ids'] );
```

Change `$order_by` to `'like'`

Comment: Yes But i have display as top is post comment like,
post more like display as top

Comment: let's chat here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145007/room-for-ahmed-ginani-and-savan-dholu